# Excel Custom Function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, excel, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I want to create a excel custom function in reactjs. I am not getting any idea about it. If any one have idea about custom function in reactjs. plz share that. if anyone have any documentation link plz share that. Plz share any github link of project.

Answer (score 0):

A custom function does not normally have any UI, so there would be no use for React in a custom function. You can launch a dialog from a custom function by calling OfficeRuntime.displayWebDialog. The URL that you pass to this method can be a page that is formatted with React.